# Cannot start clangd lsp server with neovim on windows

Tags: c++, lua, clang, visual-studio-2022, neovim

I'm trying to create a neovim configuration that will allow me to work with c++ projects generated with cmake.

I've installed the `nvim-lspconfig` plugin, and I've installed clang with Visual Studio 2022 installer (both voices, `clang-cl and clang-compiler`). But when I cd a cmake root folder in neovim, when I open a c++ file nothing will happen. I don't see even errors. It's like the server is not working.

How can I set neovim in order to use clang shipped with Visual Studio 2022?

This is my `init.lua`:

```lua
--- Require ---

local utils = require('utils') -- just to set some keys, not related to the clang problem.

--- Options ---

-- Add number to rows

utils.opt('o', 'number', true)

-- Set indentation of files
local indent = 2
utils.opt('b', 'expandtab', true)
utils.opt('b', 'shiftwidth', indent)
utils.opt('b', 'smartindent', true)
utils.opt('b', 'tabstop', indent)
utils.opt('b', 'autoindent', true)
utils.opt('o', 'smarttab', true)
utils.opt('b', 'softtabstop', indent)

-- Enable the mouse
utils.opt('o', 'mouse', 'a')

-- Set nocompatible mode for more powerful commands
utils.opt('o', 'compatible', false)

-- Set some search options
utils.opt('o', 'showmatch', true)
utils.opt('o', 'ignorecase', true)
utils.opt('o', 'hlsearch', true)
utils.opt('o', 'incsearch', true)

-- Set options for color scheme
utils.opt('o', 'termguicolors', true)

--- Keymappings ---

-- Remap jj to escape in insert mode
utils.map('i', 'jj', '<Esc>')
utils.map('n', 'JJJJ', '<Nop>')

-- Swap ; and :
utils.map('n', ':', ';')
utils.map('n', ';', ':')

-- Start plugin section. Use this section in order to install new plugins to
-- neovim.
--
-- In order to install a new plugin, you need to put in this section the
-- repository where it can be found, and then refresh the plugin list by
-- installing them with the command:
--
-- :PlugInstall

-- Auto install vim-plug that's a plugin manager
local vimplugrepository = ''
local installpath = vim.fn.stdpath('config')..'/autoload'
local vimpluginstallpath = installpath..'/plug.vim'
local vimplugrepository = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim'
if vim.fn.empty(vim.fn.glob(vimpluginstallpath)) > 0 then
  vim.api.nvim_command('!curl -flo '..vimpluginstallpath..' --create-dirs '..vimplugrepository)
  vim.cmd 'autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall'
end
local Plug = vim.fn['plug#']

-- Put plugins in this section. Define a Plug with the repository of the plugin that you want

vim.call('plug#begin', installpath)

-- Vim airline. This plugin creates a nice status bar with more features than
-- standard one.
Plug 'https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline'

-- NerdTree is a plugin for showing a tree folder structure of the filesystem.
Plug 'https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree'

-- Vim color schemes
Plug 'https://github.com/rafi/awesome-vim-colorschemes'

-- Developer icons
Plug 'https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons'

-- Surrounding with parenthesis and xml tags with cs command and more
Plug 'https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround'

-- Show trailing whitespaces and use the command :StripWhitespace for removing
-- them
Plug 'https://github.com/ntpeters/vim-better-whitespace.git'

-- Install the LSP server for configuring it with clangd for code completition
-- in C++
Plug 'https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig'

-- An interesting theme
Plug 'https://github.com/Pocco81/Catppuccino.nvim'

-- CMake integration. It includes following commands:
-- :CMakeGenerate - it generates the project
-- :CMakeBuild - It builds the project.
-- :CMakeSwitch <config> - It switches between configurations
Plug 'https://github.com/cdelledonne/vim-cmake'

vim.call('plug#end')

--- PLUGINS CONFIGURATION ---

-- Nerdtree

-- Configure keys so with ctrlf go to the tree, with ctrl+n open the tree, and
-- ctrl+t toggle the tree
utils.map('n', '<C-f>', ':NERDTreeFocus<CR>')
utils.map('n', '<C-n>', ':NERDTree<CR>')
utils.map('n', '<C-t>', ':NERDTreeToggle<CR>')

--- LSP CONFIG ---

-- Main configuration
local lspremapopts = { noremap = true, silent = true }
vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>e', vim.diagnostic.open_float, lspremapopts)
vim.keymap.set('n', '[d', vim.diagnostic.goto_prev, lspremapopts)
vim.keymap.set('n', ']d', vim.diagnostic.goto_next, lspremapopts)
vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>q', vim.diagnostic.setloclist, lspremapopts)

-- Use an on_attach function to only map the following keys
-- after the language server attaches to the current buffer
local on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
  -- Enable completition triggered by <c-x><c-o>
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(bufnr, 'omnifunc', 'v:lua.vim.lsp.omnifunc')

  -- Mappings
  -- See ':help vim.lsp.*
  local bufopts = { noremap = true, silent = true, buffer = bufnr }
  vim.keymap.set('n', 'gD', vim.lsp.buf.declaration, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', 'gd', vim.lsp.buf.definition, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', 'K', vim.lsp.buf.hover, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', 'gi', vim.lsp.buf.implementation, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<C-k>', vim.lsp.buf.signature_help, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>wa', vim.lsp.buf.add_workspace_folder, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>wr', vim.lsp.buf.remove_workspace_folder, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>wl', function ()
    print(vim.inspect(vim.lsp.buf.list_workspace_folders()))
  end, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>D', vim.lsp.buf.type_definition, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>rn', vim.lsp.buf.rename, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>ca', vim.lsp.buf.code_action, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', 'gr', vim.lsp.buf.references, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>f', vim.lsp.buf.formatting, bufopts)
end

-- Now the servers must be defined and set. In order to load them it's
-- convenient to define them in an array and use a loop.
local servers = { 'pyright', 'clangd' }
for _, lsp in pairs(servers) do
  require('lspconfig')[lsp].setup {
    on_attach = on_attach,
    flags = {
      debounce_text_changes = 150
    }
  }
end


--- COLOR SCHEME ---

vim.cmd[[colorscheme catppuccin]]
```

Comment: I had this because I forgot to run `:LspInstall clangd` on a new machine. It's odd that LspInfo does not tell you if the language servers you have configured are installed, too. Note I did already have a `clangd` installed and available in path; this is something different evidently.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `:LspInfo` to see if a client is attached to the buffer. If it is, you can run `:LspLog` to get more info on what the source of the problem might be. If it is not, you have an issue with the configuration.

The LSP client needs to be able to find `clangd`. So, it either needs to be in your path, or you need to fully specify the path.

The clang installed by VS is not in your path. It will be added to your path if you run neovim from the Visual Studio Developer (Command Prompt|PowerShell).

You can also manually specify the full path with:

```
require('lspconfig')['clangd'].setup {
  on_attach = on_attach,
  cmd = { '<full path to clangd>' }
  flags = {
    debounce_text_changes = 150
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure, but LspLog doesn't display anything if a client doesn't get attached in the first place. So this isn't the right way to debug this problem.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn This is indeed the right way to debug. a) determine if it is attached or not, b) fix your config if not, or read the log. If you have a way to figure out what is the source of the problem when it is not attached, please provide the answer.